# Robocopy folder IF ALL files in the folder are older than 60 days

Tags: batch-file, robocopy

I am using this little batch file to archive my files.

```
:: Move the files

robocopy P:\Folder1 Q:\Folder2 /move  /e /minage:60

:: Delete empty folders

q:

cd Folder2

for /f "tokens=*" %%d in ('dir /ad/b/s ^| sort /R') do rd "%%d"

pause >nul
```

However, the problem is that lots of my folders contain files with different ages. And I end up with split folders in source and destination.

Can you, please, help me to make the bat file move only the folders in which ALL the files are older than 60 days?

Thanks

Comment: I guess you can run robocopy in verbose list mode first by adding `/L /V /njh /njs|find "too new"` and on next line `if errorlevel 1 goto DoMove`

Comment: Thanks  A LOT for your comment. Can you write the entire code for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First run robocopy in list-only mode and if there were no "too new" files then do the actual move operation:

```
robocopy P:\Folder1 Q:\Folder2 /s /minage:60 /L /V /njh /njs | find "too new" >nul
if %errorlevel% EQU 0 (
    robocopy P:\Folder1 Q:\Folder2 /move /s /minage:60
)

pause >nul
```

With `/s` parameter instead of `/e` there's no need to delete empty folders, hopefully.